# How to add start tag and end tag and include elements in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Country>
    <State>
        <Cali></Cali>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Texas></Texas>
    </State> 
</Country>
```

Actual xml. I want to add start tag and end tag at specific points while including elements.

Wanted output:

```
<Country>
  <States> <!-- How to add start tag? -->
    <State>
        <Cali></Cali>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Texas></Texas>
    </State> 
  </States> <!-- How to add end tag? -->
</Country>
```

So far my code...

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(test.xml);
var statesElement = new XElement("States");
doc.Root.Element("Country").Add(statesElement);
```

And of course i get the following output... And now I'm just stuck and ask how can I include elements?

```
<Country>
    <State>
        <Cali></Cali>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Texas></Texas>
    </State> 
  <States /> <!-- Not wanted. -->
</Country>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done into the issue and what attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. See [ask] for more tips on asking questions that are less likely to be downvoted.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I appreciate your suggestion for improvement. I edited my question. Hope you can follow me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the elements from the root node and add to the new node:

```cs
string xml = @"<Country>
    <State>
        <Cali></Cali>
    </State>
    <State>
        <Texas></Texas>
    </State> 
</Country>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XElement newElement = new XElement("States");
doc.Root.Add(newElement);
foreach(var element in doc.Root.Elements("State").ToList()){
    element.Remove();
    newElement.Add(element);
}
```

This will output

```xml
<Country>
  <States>
    <State>
      <Cali></Cali>
    </State>
    <State>
      <Texas></Texas>
    </State>
  </States>
</Country>
```

Also, note that `Country` is your root, so there is no need for `Root.Element("Country")`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this way...

```
string xml = @" <Country>
                    <State>
                        <Cali></Cali>
                    </State>
                    <State>
                        <Texas></Texas>
                    </State> 
                </Country>";
```

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement newElement = new XElement("States");
            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Descendants().Count(); i++)
            {
                foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Elements("State"))
                {
                    element.Remove();
                    newElement.Add(element);
                }
            }
            doc.Root.Add(newElement);
```